# Duplicate output in joining 3 tables in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Good Day everyone! I got a problem of duplicate output from my MySql Stored Procedure and as I look on the web, my syntax is somehow correct. Can anybody help me please. here is my code:

```
 DELIMITER $$

USE `xxxxxx`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `VIEW_GCELC_DELEGATE_SP`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `VIEW_GCELC_DELEGATE_SP`(
)
BEGIN
    SELECT lc_data.indicode, lc_indi.lastname, lc_indi.firstname, lc_org.orgname
    FROM tb_gcelc_data AS lc_data
    INNER JOIN tb_gcelc_orgreg AS lc_org ON lc_data.orgcode = lc_org.orgcode
    INNER JOIN tb_gcelc_indireg AS lc_indi ON lc_data.orgcode = lc_indi.orgcode
    WHERE lc_data.year = YEAR(CURDATE())
    ORDER BY lc_org.orgname;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here is the output:

```
indicode lastname  firstname orgname

379257  Testing Testing Company Number One
957914  Testing Testing Company Number One
729065  Testing Testing Company Number One
389915  Testing Testing Company Number One
652854  Testing Testing Company Number One
696817  Testing Testing Company Number One
469712  Testing Testing Company Number One
450179  Testing Testing Company Number One
966966  Testing Testing Company Number One
379257  Test Mode Testing Again Company Number One
957914  Test Mode Testing Again Company Number One
729065  Test Mode Testing Again Company Number One
389915  Test Mode Testing Again Company Number One
652854  Test Mode Testing Again Company Number One
696817  Test Mode Testing Again Company Number One
469712  Test Mode Testing Again Company Number One
450179  Test Mode Testing Again Company Number One
966966  Test Mode Testing Again Company Number One
379257  More  Test More Company Number One
957914  More  Test More Company Number One
729065  More  Test More Company Number One
389915  More  Test More Company Number One
652854  More  Test More Company Number One
696817  More  Test More Company Number One
469712  More  Test More Company Number One
450179  More  Test More Company Number One
966966  More  Test More Company Number One
```

It's pretty weird because of loop output.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you show sample data?

Comment: Maybe my eyes are failing me but I don't see any duplicate rows in your sample output.

Comment: 379257 has 3 output. and the name Testing Testing has 9 output.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all who replied. Anyways, I finally solved my problem. I just analyse why i'm getting multiple Orgname and it's because of this:

```
INNER JOIN tb_gcelc_indireg AS lc_indi ON lc_data.orgcode = lc_indi.orgcode
```

and I change it into

```
LEFT JOIN tb_gcelc_indireg AS lc_indi ON lc_data.indicode = lc_indi.indicode
```

there! and I'm my problem is now solved. Thank you again.